# SCP command equivalent in chef-solo

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm very new to chef. I'm trying to move a .tar file from my local machine(MAC) to a VM(In same machine). I tried remove_directory, remote_file and deploy. It didn't work. Can anyone guide me..?

Comment: You have to make the file reachable for the `remote_file` resource (thus through [HTTP(S) or FTP](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/ececa3438f122d25986fa34557694fa1e86527d2/lib/chef/provider/remote_file/fetcher.rb). If you really only plan to use Vagrant, you can use the built-in mount `/vagrant` inside the VM.

Comment: I'm using vagrant for my vm's. But I want to push the file from chef-solo. Can you give me an example or a reference where I can find any further details...?

Comment: Upload the file to somewhere, where it's reachable through HTTP(S). That's it.

Comment: @StephenKing In https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/06/24/from-solo-to-zero-migrating-to-chef-client-local-mode/ link it says "In old days Chef was to scp (or worse, ftp) giant tarballs of recipes & cookbooks from system to system"

Comment: And? This has nothing to do with your problem. That comment is targeted at chef-solo mode, where the cookbooks aren't downloaded from the chef server.